# Why Do My WinForms Controls Look Flat?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, button, windows-10

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013/2015 and my operating system is Windows 10. I would like to know why my WinForms controls look so flat. I have both enabled and disabled EnableVisualStyles. Perhaps this is a Windows 10 issue? Why would these controls be lacking a 3D look and feel?

Thanks much,

Comment: The 3D look is bell-bottom pants, it would make your UI design look hopelessly outdated and unmaintained.  In a way that makes a VB6 app recognizable from a hundred feet away.  Not the kind of impression you ever want to make when you just finished sweating on your app.  You automagically get the OS styling preferences in winforms without having to write any code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The windows 10 theme itself is very flat, and winforms adopts the visual style of whatever version of windows you are running.

So you aren't doing anything wrong, that is just how windows 10 UI elements look.

If you were to run your application on windows 7, it would look more 3D.